# Save Illustrator gradients to Libraries

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, adobe-library

I would like to save some gradient fills to my (Adobe-)Library in Illustrator for use in other projects. When I select a graphic with a gradient fill I can only save the graphic to my Library, not the gradient fill as a swatch itself. I use Illustrator CC (26.0.3)
What do I do wrong or is there a work-around? Thanks

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. As far as I know it's not possible to store a gradient in a library, only a graphic filled with a gradient as you already mentioned.  If you want to transfer the gradient into another document, drag the graphic from the library, and then embed it. Then you can use the gradient in your document, and add it to your swatches.

Answer (score 1):

You *can not* save gradient or pattern swatches to .ase library files - the cross-application universal Adobe swatches library format.

You **can** save gradient or pattern swatches to .ai library files - an Illustrator-only swatch format.

Just choose `Save Swatch Library as AI` from the **Swatches Panel** menu.

The *only* difference is you **won't** be able to load the library in Photoshop, or InDesign, etc. if it is saved as an .ai file. It will *only* work for Illustrator.

---

In fact, you don't necessarily need to do anything special to save the swatches. Just save an .ai file containing the swatches like you'd save *any* .ai file. You can then load that, or any .ai file, using the Swatches Panel menu to load a library and the swatches will load - even if they weren't *specifically* saved as a library.